# The nodes doesn't attach to the EKS cluster via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm using 0.14.2 Terraform version. I'm trying to deploy an EKS cluster with two nodes with this code:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  enabled_cluster_log_types = []
  name                      = var.cluster_name
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version                   = var.eks_version
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = flatten([ aws_subnet.private.*.id, aws_subnet.public.*.id ])
    security_group_ids      = []
    endpoint_private_access = "true"
    endpoint_public_access  = "true"
  }
  tags = var.tags[terraform.workspace]

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster_AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster_AmazonEKSServicePolicy,
    aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cluster
  ]
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "eks-managenodes" {
  for_each                    = local.ob
  
  name_prefix                 = "${var.cluster_name}-launch-${each.value}"
  image_id                    = "ami-038341f2c72928ada"
  instance_type               = "t3.medium"
  user_data = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      set -o xtrace
      /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${var.cluster_name}
      EOF

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size = 30
    volume_type = "gp2"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "eks-asg" {
  for_each        = local.ob

  desired_capacity     = 1
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.eks-managenodes[each.value].id
  max_size             = 1
  min_size             = 1
  name                 = "${var.cluster_name}-node-${each.value}"
  vpc_zone_identifier  = aws_subnet.private.*.id

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "eks-manage-node-${each.value}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}"
    value               = "owned"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_launch_configuration.eks-managenodes,
    aws_eks_cluster.cluster
  ]
}
```

Then, the cluster deploy fine, the ASG and the EC2 instances deploy fine, but the problem is that these instances doesn't attach to the corresponding cluster and I don't find the problem..

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nodes can fail to join a cluster for a variety of reasons.

1. a failure during cloud-init may be preventing them from registering with the cluster control plane.
2. there may be IAM authentication failures.

Debugging steps:

1. Ssh into a node and check `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to ensure that it completed without error.
2. verify that `kubelet` and `aws-node` processes are running on the ec2 nodes.  Both should show up in `ps`
3. check that `/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh` exists.  Try invoking it as root with the arguments  `/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint '${endpoint}' --b64-cluster-ca '${cluster_ca_data}' '${cluster_name}'` using the variables sourced from the EKS overview page in the AWS ui.
4. check the `aws-auth` config map in `kube-system` and verify the ec2 role is mapped like this:

```
    mapRoles: |
      - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/<node role>
        username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
        groups:
          - system:bootstrappers
          - system:nodes
```

as without this the node will not be able to authenticate to the cluster.

When in doubt, try the newest version of the EKS ami for your cluster's kubernetes version - some AMIs are broken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mcfinnigan. I just see the log and I got some errors. One of this is this:  Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Comment: @HumbertoLantero that most likely means your EC2 node does not have an instance profile bound that permits it to register with EKS.

Comment: true, I attach the instance profile and now I dont get this error, but I'm getting other one: nvidia-smi not found .. I'm using the optimized AMI for my region..

Comment: @HumbertoLantero : Did you find a solution for this ? I am also getting the same error "nvidia-smi not found"

Comment: @SujeetPadhi Yes, the problem was the AMI. You have to use the optimized AMI proposed by AWS.

Comment: @HumbertoLantero: Yeah I figured it out and used the AWS proposed AMIs.

Answer (score -1):

Foe the EKS cluster to own those nodes you will have to use the [AWS EKS Node Group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group) and not [EC2 Launch Configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_configuration) I believe.

From the same link in documentation below, the cluster_name will be referencing the EKD cluster you created.

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.example.name
  node_group_name = "example"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.example[*].id

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 1
    min_size     = 1
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I know this choice.. The problem is that using this choice I dont have access to the Instance IDs to monitoring after in cloudwatch.. So I only can use the ASG..

Comment: Ah! Help me understand why you won't get ID if you use EKS node group?

Comment: Because the output of this resource doesnt expose the instance IDs.. :S

Comment: @VishalBiyani it is not necessary to use a nodegroup for EKS, this is merely the new pattern as opposed to the legacy asg + launchconfig

Comment: Thanks @mcfinnigan I think my answer then is technically incorrect. May be I should delete it to avoid confusion for others!